# BeatifulSoap retornando apenas uma linha

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Quando faço um scraping nessa página: https://ipinfo.io/countries/br, o ***for*** está me retornando apenas o primeiro registro encontrado da tabela, já tentei de várias formas, alterando as tags e sintaxes mas não está funcionando e não achei nada no material que me ajude. Onde eu estou errando?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("https://ipinfo.io/countries/br")
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

linhas = bs.find_all('table', {'class': 'table table-responsive'})

for i in linhas:
    filhas = i.findChildren('td')
    print(filhas[0])
    print(filhas[1])
    print(filhas[2])
    
asn, empresa, ips = [], [], []
for i in linhas:
    children = i.findChildren('td')
    asn.append(children[0].text)
    empresa.append(children[1].text)
    ips.append(children[2].text)
    
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ASN': asn, 'Empresa': empresa, 'Qtde IP': ips})

df.head()
```

Saída:

|  | ASN | Empresa | Qtde IP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AS26599 | TELEFÔNICA BRASIL S.A | 12,060,672 |

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Você colocou uma imagem do código e/ou mensagem de erro. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é! Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar o código e alterar algo dentro. Clique no link [edit] e **coloque o código/erro como texto**. Veja mais sobre isso nesses links - [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3774), [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774)

Comment: Só existe uma `table` nesse html, então `find_all('table')` só vai retornar um elemento mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo um pouco da sua lógica implementei o seguinte código:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_base = 'https://ipinfo.io/countries/br'

r = requests.get(url_base)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
```

Aqui pegamos a table que você deseja usar

```
table = soup.find('table', {'class':'table table-responsive'})
```

De dentro da tabela extraímos o cabeçalho que será usado no data frame

```
header = [th.text for th in table.find_all('th')]
```

Aqui extraímos as td com os seus respectivos textos, serão os registros do data frame

```
td = [[td.text for td in tr.find_all('td', {'class': 'p-3'}) if td] for tr in table.find_all('tr')[1:]]
```

Aqui criamos o data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(td, columns=header)
df
```

Saída:

|  | ASN | Name | Num IPs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AS26599 | TELEFÔNICA BRASIL S.A | 12,060,672 |
| 1 | AS26615 | TIM S/A | 9,623,296 |
| 2 | AS28573 | CLARO S.A. | 9,553,408 |
| 3 | AS7738 | Telemar Norte Leste S.A. | 7,709,696 |
| 4 | AS4230 | CLARO S.A. | 5,585,152 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2495 | AS264247 | Maila Networks | 1,024 |
| 2496 | AS264246 | Globaltech Telecomunicações e Informatica Ltda ME | 1,024 |
| 2497 | AS264245 | Turkeynet Ltda. | 1,024 |
| 2498 | AS264244 | SPEED NET SERVIÇOS DE TELECOMUNICAÇOES LTDA-ME | 1,024 |
| 2499 | AS264242 | Diogo Cássio Cabral Me | 1,024 |

---

Uma forma mais simples de fazer é utilizando o read_html do pandas:

```
df = pd.read_html(url_base)[0]

df
```

Saída:

|  | ASN | Name | Num IPs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AS26599 | TELEFÔNICA BRASIL S.A | 12060672 |
| 1 | AS26615 | TIM S/A | 9623296 |
| 2 | AS28573 | CLARO S.A. | 9553408 |
| 3 | AS7738 | Telemar Norte Leste S.A. | 7709696 |
| 4 | AS4230 | CLARO S.A. | 5585152 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2495 | AS264247 | Maila Networks | 1024 |
| 2496 | AS264246 | Globaltech Telecomunicações e Informatica Ltda ME | 1024 |
| 2497 | AS264245 | Turkeynet Ltda. | 1024 |
| 2498 | AS264244 | SPEED NET SERVIÇOS DE TELECOMUNICAÇOES LTDA-ME | 1024 |
| 2499 | AS264242 | Diogo Cássio Cabral Me | 1024 |